# How do you create an Array from information that a Table holds in its Rows?

Tags: arrays, ruby, html-table, row, watir

I have a Table that has an arbitrary amount of Rows.
In these Rows I have names that are in Columns within the Rows that I want to pull and place into an Array.
The table that I want to pull from looks like this:

```
<table id="team-1200d35e-7528-11e0-9a7d-00b7c9f2a9c6-table" class="grid" style="width: 748px;">
   <tbody>
     <tr class="team-member odd" row="1" team="0" data-id="66c36a98-7832-11e0-968b-5e9370556780" name="Barbara Gordon">
     </tr>
     <tr class="team-member even" row="5" team="0" data-id="a9042cb6-7527-11e0-9a7d-00b7c9f2a9c6" name="Bruce Wayne">
     </tr>
     <tr class="team-member even" row="0" team="0" data-id="39daacee-7832-11e0-968b-5e9370556780" name="Dick Grayson">
     </tr>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

The Information from each row that I want to pull is the name="".

How can I pull just the names and create an array out of this?

Comment: In Ruby, you cannot have an array with an infinite amount of rows. You probably meant an arbitrary amount of rows.

Comment: @sawa: Thank you. Definitely used the wrong word there haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is just a string you can parse it as an XML document using, say [REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/) (which appears to be a manual install), and extract the name attributes like so:

```
require 'rexml'
names = []
doc = REXML::Document.new(my_table_data)
doc.elements.each('table/tbody/tr') do |el|
  names << el.attributes['name'] if el.attributes['name']
end
names # => ['Barbara Gordon', 'Bruce Wayne', 'Dick Grayson']
```

Or similarly using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) (which can be installed as a gem):

```
require 'nokogiri'
names = []
doc = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(my_table_data)
doc.xpath('table/tbody/tr[@name]').each do |el|
  names << el['name']
end
names # => ['Barbara Gordon', 'Bruce Wayne', 'Dick Grayson']
```

You could get fancier and split the first/last names by whitespace but that will wreak havoc for people whose first name includes a space...

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of where I could learn more about REXML. I have never used this before. Is it a gem?

Comment: @Curtis Miller: I've linked the [REXML website](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/) from my post.  It looks like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) is easier to install (and possibly to use) though, so you might want to go that route instead.

Comment: I have opened a ticket for my problems with Nokogiri here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300078/what-i-am-doing-wrong-or-what-i-am-missing-to-install-nokogiri but I am still having issues trying to get either of these to work.